# BufferedReader and FileReader not working in

Tags: java, file-io, io, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm just trying to read text from an existing file.txt But this program shows 2 errors
for the FileReader(file)) it says : **Expected 0 arguments but found 1** 
and for reader.readLine() it says : **Cannot resolve method 'readLine' in 'BufferedReader'**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    File file = new File("fileExample.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
       reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have named your own class `BufferedReader`, which clashes with the standard class `java.io.BufferedReader`. Rename your own class, to avoid confusion and errors.

Comment: Note that this code has deplorable exception handling (Just make your main `throws Exception` and get rid of all try/catch blocks - better code _and_ shorter code, winwin!), should be using try-with-resources, FileReader should never be used (broken charsets). Not a single line of it is proper java, unfortunately. things to search the web for tutorials: The API in `java.nio.file`, the try-with-resources (also known as ARM) construct, charsets.

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot and solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your class to something other than `BufferedReader`, and import the right class from the JDK:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

Otherwise the compiler will look for a constructor of your own class.

Note about exception handling: given the code you have, if an IOException occurs when creating the BufferedReader, then the subsequent code will throw a NullPointerException. It may be better to just wrap the entire code in a try-with-resources block, or have the main method `throws IOException`.